# What data type should be used to store numbers like 10^6 and 10^-9?

Tags: mysql

I need to store some very large and small numbers in the database. I am going to be using these numbers as the parameter for `ORDER BY` in `SELECT` statements.

So, for example, one column might have the value

```
0.000000001
```

While another might have the value

```
1000000
```

What datatype should I use to store these values? I'm thinking `double`, but I want to make sure.

Comment: double would do, but note that many decimal/fractional numbers can't be represented as floats properly. don't depend on things working exactly as you planned.

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html  and choose the one it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go with a DECIMAL for very small numbers because it allows a fixed decimal point. If your large numbers don't have decimal precision, an INT data type should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

I'd simply use `integer` to store it.

Comment: You'd use an integer to store 10^-9?

Comment: Not the number `10^-9` but the calculated value.

Comment: Oh, so you mean you can store `0.00000001` in an integer?